# Eclipse Luna : losing hotkeys and getting back with focus change

Tags: eclipse

I have seen some questions about eclipse hotkeys, but not exactly like mine :

I have very weird behaviour with eclipse Luna :
I am typing some text in the editor window, and suddenly, all the hotkeys are not working anymore ( ctrl-s ctrl-z ctrl-f etc...).
Nevertheless,the keyboard is still working, I can enter some more text, use arrow keys : nothing tells I have lost the focus in the editor window.

I just click in a side view window to lose focus in the editor,
and click again in editor window to get the focus back, and that's it : the hotkeys are back.

I was using eclipse Keppler before Luna, there were not such a behaviour with Keppler.

As I am losing the hotkeys every minute, I really need to solve this problem : any idea ?

NOTE : I am using ubuntu 12.04 (gnome)

Comment: Do you use linux and gnome?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm looking for solution too. It's appears on Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS with gnome and GTK3. I will try to purge gnome and try it with kde or like.

Comment: Do you have pydev and ShellEd plugins ?

Comment: No, I'm trying also Eclipse classic without plugins.

Answer (score 0):

After one year I think I may have found how to fix it ...

I have a 12.04 precise with latest kernel (3.2.0-80-generic) and unity and with gnome compatibility settings enabled as well.

### Compiz

I started to look at the [Compiz Config Setting Manager](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/compizconfig-settings-manager/)

### Disable The Workaround

As Eclipse is written in Java I found that maybe disabling fixes related to it could help.

From the CompizConfig Settings Manager go to Utility->Workarounds and disable:

- Java Window Fix
- Java Taskbar Fix

I actually have disable all the workaround and not just those. I restarted Eclipse and it seems now to work.  (NOTE: I believe you may have Compiz running even if you don't use unity)

### Result

I do not have to unfocus or refocus. It seems to work pretty well. Interleaving ctrl-s, ctrl-z and ctrl-f works fine. (but I just tested few minutes, the system is unstable so I opted for another solution, see below)

### Final Solution for me

I login with gnome classic without 3D effect

Answer (score 0):

Workaroud I actually use:

```
GDK_CORE_DEVICE_EVENTS=1 ./eclipse
```

I don't know how long would it be work.